# Adding, deleting elements as per autocomplete results - updated

Tags: javascript, jquery

- I am working on a Python/Django project which has turned into a JavaScript/jQuery project due to the amount of asynchronous functionality that I thought to add.
- There is a [JavaScript file](https://github.com/anshbansal/Bookmarker/blob/master/static/BookMarker/js/bookmarker.js) which is doing everything for the JS side. I am a newbie in JavaScript/jQuery and am starting to think that this is going to become a big problem soon.
- I asked for a [previous review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51645/adding-deleting-elements-as-per-autocomplete-results) but as I never got one there and the file has changed a lot since then I am placing part of the file where I think something can be be improved.

Some functions which are being used by the code:

```
function bind_events(cur_obj, e) {
    var trigger_name = "";
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        trigger_name = EV_ENTER_KEY;
    } else if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == "N".charCodeAt(0)) {
        trigger_name = EV_ALT_N;
    }
    $(cur_obj).trigger(trigger_name);
}

//Auxiliary functions for categories
function get_all_categories() {
    var class_ids = [];
    $(CLASS_DEL_CATEGORY).each(function () {
        class_ids.push(get_class_string(this, 11));
    });
    return class_ids.join(",");
}

function enter_category(category_box, trigger_event, trigger_data) {
    if (value_in_selector(category_box, CLASS_UI_MENU_ITEM) == false) {
        alert(MSG_NOT_CATEGORY);
    } else if (value_in_selector(category_box, CLASS_CATEGORY) == true) {
        alert(MSG_CATEGORY_ADDED);
        category_box.val("");
    } else {
        category_box.trigger(trigger_event, trigger_data);
    }
}

function add_category(cur_obj, e, data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: URL_CATEGORY,
        data: {'value': $(cur_obj).val()},
        success: function (output) {
            data.cat_list.append(output);
            $(cur_obj).val("");
            if (data.trigger_obj !== undefined) {
                data.trigger_obj.trigger(data.next_trig);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The code that I think needs to be improved is below.

```
//Actions for Search's category box
CATEGORY_INPUT.on({
    keyup: function (e) {
        bind_events(this, e);
    },

    "enterKey": function () {
        enter_category($(this), EV_ADD_CATEGORY, [
            {
                cat_list: CATEGORY_LIST_SEARCH,
                trigger_obj: BOOKMARK_LIST,
                next_trig: EV_UPDATE_BOOKMARKS
            }
        ])
    },

    "addCategory": function (e, data) {
        add_category(this, e, data);
    },

    "clearAll": function () {
        $(CLASS_CATEGORY).remove();
        $(this).val("");
        BOOKMARK_LIST.trigger(EV_CLEAR_ALL);
    }
});

//Actions for Add Bookmark's category box
CATEGORY_BOX.on({
    keyup: function (e) {
        bind_events(this, e);
    },

    "enterKey": function () {
        enter_category($(this), EV_ADD_CATEGORY, [
            {
                cat_list: CATEGORY_LIST_ADD,
                trigger_obj: undefined,
                next_trig: undefined
            }
        ])
    },

    "addCategory": function (e, data) {
        add_category(this, e, data);
    }
});
```

As you can see nearly same events are bound to both with minor changes. I thought to bind events to multiple selectors but as not all are same events readability will suffer.

Any thoughts for improvements?

Comment: What are the values of `EV_ADD_CATEGORY` and `EV_ENTER_KEY`? I see those constants used in some places, but - I suspect - not _all_ the places they ought to be.

Comment: @Flambino These are strings representing the events that I wrote to avoid hard-coding at many places but I came across a problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095288/custom-events-binding-in-jquery-function-on-not-working due to which I had to hard-code the values. Not happy about it but have been unable to find a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structurally, it doesn't look too bad, although it seems inconsistent.

By convention, JavaScript uses `camelCase` naming - not `snake_case`. All your code is `snake_case`, but then you have things like `keyCode` and `charCodeAt` because that's what JS's own APIs use. So I'd encourage you to switch you code to `camelCase` in keeping with JS conventions.

You've got a number of "constants" (in quotes, since JS doesn't actually have constants), like `EV_ENTER_KEY`, which, judging from your comment, is a string (`enterKey` in this case). Sometimes you use the constants by name, other times you use them by value.

While it's true you can't do this:

```
CONST = "foo";
obj = {
  CONST: "bar"
};
```

and get an object like `{foo: "bar"}` (because JS interprets the `CONST:` literally), you can do this:

```
obj = {}
obj[CONST] = "bar";
```

And your object will be `{foo: "bar"}`.

So that would clean things up, and allow you to *actually* use constants. E.g.

```
categoryBoxEvents = {}
categoryBoxEvents.keyup = function (e) {
  bind_events(this, e);
};

categoryBoxEvents[EV_ENTER_KEY] = function () {
  enter_category($(this), EV_ADD_CATEGORY, [{
    cat_list: CATEGORY_LIST_ADD,
    trigger_obj: undefined,
    next_trig: undefined
  }]);
};

categoryBoxEvents[EV_ADD_CATEGORY] = function (e, data) {
  add_category(this, e, data);
};

CATEGORY_BOX.on(categoryBoxEvents);
```

However, don't rely on `undefined` being undefined. For mysterious reasons, `undefined` isn't a reserved word in JS, meaning that some (older) runtimes allow it be defined. Instead, use `null` or just don't set a value at all.

For instance, the event-key event handler above could simply be:

```
enter_category($(this), EV_ADD_CATEGORY, [{
  cat_list: CATEGORY_LIST_ADD
}]);
```

If you don't define `trigger_obj` and `next_trig`, they're - by definition - `undefined`.

Where you need to to check for these values, you can simply do

```
if (!data.trigger_obj) { ... }
```

because `undefined` is false'y (and so is `false`, `null`, `0`, and `""`).

Or, if you feel you should be (needlessly) exact:

```
if (typeof data.trigger_obj === 'undefined') { ... }
```

I'd also skip a lot of the proxy-functions you've got going on. For instance, `add_category` is called from 2 identical wrapper functions, only so its 1st argument can be set. Don't bother. Try this instead:

```
function add_category(e, data) {
  var $this = $(this); // just use `this`
  $.ajax({
    url: URL_CATEGORY,
    data: { value: $this.val() },
    success: function (output) {
      data.cat_list.append(output);
      $this.val("");
      if(data.trigger_obj && data.next_trig) {
        data.trigger_obj.trigger(data.next_trig);
      }
    }
  });
}

// ... snip ...

categoryBoxEvents[EV_ADD_CATEGORY] = add_category;
```

Now, when `add_category` is called, its `this` will automatically be the right object. No need for you to specify it. And if you ever need to call `add_category` in a different context, you can use [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), or bind it to an object with `bind()` (not supported on all browsers) or `jQuery.proxy()`.

Lastly, I think you may be a bit trigger-happy (pardon the pun). You're handling events by triggering a lot of other events, which in turn seem to trigger events and so on. While that does decouple your code, it also introduces some overhead. It might make the code simpler to skip some of the trigger-cascades in favor of just calling functions directly. Same goes for the constants, which, while useful in many cases, seem a little excessive. Functions are first-class objects, so you can simply pass them around instead of referring to them.

Comment: I understand that functions can be passed as arguments but where in this code can passing functions can be useful?

Comment: @AseemBansal It's just as an alternative to using `trigger` everywhere. Triggering events require you to a) trigger an event with a given name on a given obj, and b) have a listener for that same given name on that same given object so function `x` will be called. Alternatively, you could simply replace all that with a direct call to function `x`. E.g. `bind_events` could take a obj of eventname/handler pairs and call them directly, instead of setting up events to call them indirectly

Comment: OMG I was so excited with AJAX/jQuery that I had actually forgotten that event based programming is not necessary in Javascript. I am still in shock after realizing this by your comment.

Comment: As my javascript is currently stuck in triggers how would you suggest going to functions? I am thinking of using `bind_events` to route to proper functions. As there are many elements in my html setting a `switch` should be a good idea for selecting events for each element. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @AseemBansal You can perhaps use more or less the same structure, i.e. make an object like `{ "13": function () {...} }`, and, in your `bind_events` do something like `if(typeof handlers[keycode] === 'function') handlers[keycode]();` (that's semi-pseudo code, and not far from how `trigger` etc. works internally, but it's still more direct

Comment: @AseemBansal [Here's an old answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/18215/14370) I wrote, which might give you some ideas. The setup is a little different, but the event handling is straightforward enough. Know, however, that your current event-triggering code isn't _wrong_ in any way; it just seems a little cumbersome to me. One layer of abstraction too many, so to speak.